# How to trigger on solar noon in Home Assistant?

Tags: smart-home, home-assistant

The sun component has `sunset` and `sunrise` events, but I would like to trigger on 
[solar noon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noon). [This page](https://www.home-assistant.io/docs/automation/trigger/#sun-trigger) tells me I can use the elevation for this. What number should I enter to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious answer would be to use the `azimuth` parameter, and check for 180 (south). The sun component also has a 'rising' state (before noon), and `next_noon` time.

If you follow the [link](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/AltAz.php) to the US Naval observatory, you can print out a table of solar position for any particular location, on any particular date. For my location (52N), I see the sun crosses the horizon around 7am, 4pm  at this time of year, and reaches a maximum elevation of 21.5 degrees. In the middle of the summer at the same location, I get 4am, 8pm and 61 degrees elevation.

There is no simple calculation in this case. The zero points are constant as being the start and end of the day (from which you can pick earlier or later references), but the elevation does not make any correction for your location or the time of year.

Regardless of how you determine the correct angle for 'noon', you would need to repeatedly update this based on the date.

A better approach might be to determine the relevant time of day based on location, since a constant UTC time might be a close enough approximation.  Here, 12:00 is good enough (but I have the meridian just a few miles away).